# docker swarm access service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How to access swarm services on a multi-host `docker swarm`.

For a docker swarm, lets say that the services are named: **abc, pqr, xyz**

If the services are placed in the **same** host, they are able to access by http://pqr/a or http://xyz/a

but if they are on **different** host they are not able to access by  http://pqr/a or http://xyz/a. Even ping to the other service names are not working.

```
docker service create --constraint 'node.labels.momachinename == t4301' --name abc --network=ni_default mo-vo:7.10.0s node /a/src/start.js

docker service create --constraint 'node.labels.momachinename == t4302' --name pqr --network=ni_default mo-vo:7.10.0s node /a/src/start.js

docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
d7478273de19        bridge              bridge              local
485112e08c0f        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
c8a75eb27f1f        host                host                local
5rmqgswur2lp        ingress             overlay             swarm
q26p8tdr0xw6        networld            overlay             swarm
d2kf3bfdbmol        ni_default          overlay             swarm
64094b86b804        none                null                local
```

Comment: Actually, it should work from another host, did you use `docker overlay network` (required to use service name DNS in multihost context)?

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel .. edited commands ..

Comment: Commands seem to be fine, overlay network too... From where are you issuing the http / ping commands? hosts or in running containers?

Comment: docker exec -it ... bash ,, then ping ..

Comment: right thing, are you sure you services are up `docker service ls` is ok?

Comment: yes ok,, some of the services were started with stack ,, while some from command line ,,  but in the same network, will that cause problems.

Comment: I don't think so. There must be something that i miss...

Answer (score 1):

From your symptoms, it sounds like you have the containers running on the same overlay network and can communicate using DNS resolution on the same host, but you're just having problems between hosts. For overlay networking between hosts, you need the following firewall rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m udp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4789 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
```

That's port 7946 for tcp/udp (this is the control port), port 4789 for tcp (this is the data port), and protocol 50 (needed for secure networks using IPSEC).